# ¿Cómo se importa y utiliza stdlib en JAVA?

Tags: java, stdin, stdout

Quiero saber cómo se importa la librería Stdlib y cómo puedo hacer para pueda leer letras desde el teclado. Es decir, recibir un input.

Comment: te refieres a la libreria stdlib de la universidad princeton? https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

En Java si quieres leer desde teclado lo más sencillo es utilizar la clase Scanner, importándola al inicio con import. La clase Scanner tiene múltiples métodos dependiendo de si quieres leer un entero, un double, texto, ...

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeerLinea {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Introduzca una línea:");
 
    String linea= stdin.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Texto:" +linea); 

   } 
}
```